# React Native Crushes when I open Debug on Android Emulator

Tags: react-native, debugging, metro-bundler, react-native-cli

```
MAP  ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1)Error: Unable to resolve module ./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4 from C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Demo\Demo - v2\Demo\Demo.Apps\demo-mobile/.:
```

None of these files exist:

```
* debugger-ui\debuggerWorker.aca173c4(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.svg|.svg)
* debugger-ui\debuggerWorker.aca173c4\index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.svg|.svg)
at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Demo\Demo - v2\Demo\Demo.Apps\demo-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:137:15)
at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Demo\Demo - v2\Demo\Demo.Apps\demo-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:260:43)
at C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Demo\Demo - v2\Demo\Demo.Apps\demo-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:177:21
at Server._resolveRelativePath (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Demo\Demo - v2\Demo\Demo.Apps\demo-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1161:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Server._explodedSourceMapForURL (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Demo\Demo - v2\Demo\Demo.Apps\demo-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1109:35)
at async Promise.all (index 1)
at async Server._symbolicate (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Demo\Demo - v2\Demo\Demo.Apps\demo-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1060:26)
at async Server._processRequest (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Demo\Demo - v2\Demo\Demo.Apps\demo-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:437:7)
```

LOG  JavaScript logs will appear in your browser console

**This is my package.json if it helps**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "metro-config": "^0.75.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.17.3",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.9",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-mask-text": "^0.13.2",
    "react-native-modern-datepicker": "^1.0.0-beta.91",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.6.2",
    "react-native-permissions": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.6.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^6.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.67.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
 }
```

If I **uninstall** the app and wipe the device I get this:

> "Requiring unknown module "undefined". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run `yarn` or `npm install`."

Restarting the project, restarting the PC does nothing. Been stuck at this for more than a day now.

Any help would be appreaciated.